How to verify correct `ConstraintMintMetadataPointerExtension` Input
Currently running some tests in a program that uses the token-22 program and my instruction has this constraint
    #[account(
        mint::decimals = 9,
        mint::authority = user,
        mint::freeze_authority = user,
        extensions::metadata_pointer::metadata_address = mint.key(),
    )]
    pub mint: InterfaceAccount<'info, Mint>,

which then outputs the errror
 'Program log: AnchorError occurred. Error Code: ConstraintMintMetadataPointerExtension. Error Number: 2030. Error Message: A metadata pointer extension constraint was violated.',
    'Program 5zjbNpnsSkCNG6zHzK183ujm6dn6fWeHWeUnk1Rzrs1Y consumed 8812 of 200000 compute units',
    'Program 5zjbNpnsSkCNG6zHzK183ujm6dn6fWeHWeUnk1Rzrs1Y failed: custom program error: 0x7ee'

My mint is derived by using the createMint function on the client side passing the TOKEN_22_PROGRAM_ID as the expected program. What could i be doing wrong?

I believe you have to initialize the mint in the instruction for the macro to work.
try adding an init and payer to this.
#[account(
        init,
        signer,
        payer = user,
        mint::decimals = 9,
        mint::authority = user,
        mint::freeze_authority = user,
        mint::token_program = token_program,
        extensions::metadata_pointer::authority = asset_controller.key(),
        extensions::metadata_pointer::metadata_address = asset_mint.key(),
    )]

This assumes you make the mint a Keypair rather than deriving it in the program which would be recommended so you don't get the address DOS'd
